# How do you create a matrix from two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, matrix

Lets say I have four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dealers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE brands (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE cars (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    brand INTEGER REFERENCES (brands.id) NOT NULL,
    name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE sells (
    id SERIAL,
    dealer INTEGER REFERENCES (dealers.id) NOT NULL,
    car INTEGER REFERENCES (cars.id) NOT NULL
)
```

If n is the number of dealers and m in the number of dealers, how to I create a n x m matrix in sql that displays the number of cars a dealer sells of a brand.

The output should look something like this:

```
Dealer    |Honda    Toyota    Tesla    
CarMax     103      204       1
CheapCars  160      320       0
GoodCars   40       20        2
OCHonda    201      0         0
```

What is the simplest, most efficient query I can use to accomplish this task?

EDIT: Changed m to be the number of dealers instead of cars

Answer (score 2):

I want to suggest that in SQL, you don't  really want a matrix.  You want the pairs of dealers and brands along with the count.  You can get this by doing:

```
select d.name as dealername, b.name as brandname, count(s.id) as numsales
from brands b cross join
     dealers d left outer join
     cars c
     on c.brand = b.id left outer join
     sells s
     on s.dealer = d.id and s.car = c.id
group by d.name, b.name;
```

If you really want this as one row per dealer, then you need to pivot the data.  If you know the brands, you can do:

```
select d.name as dealername,
       sum(case when b.name = 'Honda' and s.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as Honda,
       sum(case when b.name = 'Toyota' and s.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as Toyota,
       sum(case when b.name = 'Tesla' and s.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as Tesla
from brands b cross join
     dealers d left outer join
     cars c
     on c.brand = b.id left outer join
     sells s
     on s.dealer = d.id and s.car = c.id
group by d.name, b.name;
```

This works if you know the brands explicitly that you want.  If you don't know the brands, you will have to resort to a dynamic pivot.  A regular SQL query returns a fixed set of columns with fixed names.

Answer (score 2):

#### Basic query

```
SELECT d.name AS dealer, b.name AS brand, sells
FROM  (
   SELECT s.dealer, c.brand, count(*)::int AS sells
   FROM   sells s
   JOIN   cars  c ON c.id = s.car 
   GROUP  BY 1,2
   ) x
JOIN   brands  b ON b.id = x.brand
JOIN   dealers d ON d.id = x.dealer
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

Group first, join details later, that's typically faster.
If you want the `number of dealers instead of cars`, like you edited later, just use:
`count (DISTINCT s.dealer)` instead of `count(*)`.

#### Crosstab

Feed this to `crosstab()` from the additional Postgres module [`tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html).
Generally, you need to *list all brands explicitly* because SQL demands to know columns in advance.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   'SELECT d.name AS dealer, b.name AS brand, sells
    FROM  (
       SELECT s.dealer, c.brand, count(*)::int AS sells
       FROM   sells s
       JOIN   cars  c ON c.id = s.car
       GROUP  BY 1,2
       ) x
    JOIN   brands  b ON b.id = x.brand
    JOIN   dealers d ON d.id = x.dealer
    ORDER  BY 1,2'

   ,$$VALUES ('Honda'::text), ('Toyota'), ('Tesla')$$  -- add more ...
   ) AS t(dealer text, "Honda" int, "Toyota" int, "Tesla" int); -- add more ...
```

Ample details and explanation in this related answer:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the number of brands, then you can use `count` with `case`:

```
select d.name as dealer,
   count(case when b.name = 'Honda' then 1 end) as HondaCount,
   count(case when b.name = 'Toyota' then 1 end) as ToyotaCount,
   count(case when b.name = 'Telsa' then 1 end) as TelsaCount
from sells s
   join dealers d on s.dealer = d.id
   join cars c on s.car = c.id
   join brands b on c.brand = b.id
group by d.name
```

---

If there are dealers without any sells and you need to include those in the result, then use an `outer join` starting from the dealers table:

```
...
from dealers d
   left join sells s on s.dealer = d.id
   left join cars c on s.car = c.id
   left join brands b on c.brand = b.id
group by d.name
```

- [Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)